# Reset user profile page layout to the default value in community builder

Tags: page-layout, community-builder

I was modifying the User Profile layout and now I can't select the default value again `(1 column page layout)`, I tried to search in google for a solution and only found:

`If you change the layout of a default template page, the only way to revert to the original layout is to click Undo.`

Ok, where is the `UNDO` button in the interface?

How can I set the default layout again?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Icon you see in the above screenshot on the top right is the undo and redo buttons .

Comment: what if the undo button is not longer active :/ ?

Comment: This means you published the page and no changes between published time and now

Comment: so there is not way to set the default template anymore?

Comment: You can easily look at another community in your dev org and manually do it .Should be quick

Comment: Also still you think that layouts are not changing raise a case with support and see they can change it